# Merge query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, merge

I having the scenario of loading the data from source table to target table. If the data from source is not present in target, then i need to insert. If it is present in the target table already, then update the status of the row to 'expire' and insert the column as new row. I used Merge query to do this. I can do insert if not exists and i can do update also. But while trying to insert when matched, it says insert not allowed in 'when matched' clause.
Please help me.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us what you have already!! And explain what your tables look like!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform multiple actions for a single row of source data, you need to duplicate that row somehow.

Something like the following (making up table names, etc):

```
;WITH Source as (
    SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,t.Dupl
    FROM SourceTable,(select 0 union all select 1) t(Dupl)
)
MERGE INTO Target t
USING Source s ON t.Col1 = s.Col1 and s.Dupl=0 /* Key columns here */
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Expired = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND s.Dupl=1 THEN INSERT (Col1,Col2,Col3) VALUES (s.Col1,s.Col2,s.Col3);
```

You always want the s.Dupl condition in the not matched branch, because otherwise source rows which don't match any target rows would be inserted twice.

---

From the example you posted as a comment, I'd change:

```
MERGE target AS tar USING source AS src ON src.id = tar.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D_VALID_TO=@nowdate-1, C_IS_ACTIVE='N', D_LAST_UPDATED_DATE=@nowdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (tar.col1,tar.col2,tar.col3);
```

into:

```
;WITH SourceDupl AS (
    SELECT id,col1,col2,col3,t.Dupl
    FROM source,(select 0 union all select 1) t(Dupl)
)
MERGE target AS tar USING SourceDupl as src on src.id = tar.id AND Dupl=0
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D_VALID_TO=@nowdate-1, C_IS_ACTIVE='N', D_LAST_UPDATED_DATE=@nowdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND Dupl=1 THEN INSERT (col1,col2,col3) VALUES (src.col1,src.col2,src.col3);
```

I've changed the values in the `VALUES` clause, since in a NOT MATCHED branch, the tar table doesn't have a row to select values from.

Comment: 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' can be executed when i comes for the first time to insert the data. In next time, when the data is exists it perform update and for Insert you want me do with the same 'WHEN NOT MATCHED'  clause which declared before... Is the merge wont allow 2 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause. Can i do somethin do differentiate both the 'WHEN NOT MATCHED' clause

Comment: @user549903 - I'm not sure what you're asking for now. In the statement I've shown, if there's a matching row in the target table, both the UPDATE and INSERT will occur.

Comment: MERGE target AS tar USING source AS src ON src.id = tar.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D_VALID_TO=@nowdate-1, C_IS_ACTIVE='N', D_LAST_UPDATED_DATE=@nowdate WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT (col1,col2,col3) 
  VALUES (tar.col1,tar.col2,tar.col3);

Comment: as per my requirement, if it is matched it need to do update and insert. If it not matched, it has to do only insert

Comment: Damien, thanks a million for your help.. It updating the rows. But it is not insert a row when it is matched.

Comment: Can u please look over it again... Im expecting your response

Comment: @Robin - sorry, I had one condition in the wrong place. The Dupl=0 condition has to be in the ON, not in the ON MATCHED branch. Sorry again.

Comment: now the code has 'when matched' update
when not matched and dupl=0 insert.... Im getting this error msg...The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

Comment: dont say sorry yar.. u r helping me to learn lot.. thanks again

Comment: hey thats working man.. actually i missed to assign the Dupl=0 before checking the condition.. thats my prob... now it is working... thanks man.. really u r genious.... gr8...

Comment: @Robin - watch the 1s and 0s. The ON condition that's part of the merge should say "Dupl=0". The extra condition in the NOT MATCHED branch should say "Dupl=1"

Comment: This is another issue here damien.. when matched, it is updating the exist row to expire and inserting a new row. But it doing for all the rows. But i need only for updated source rows, insert & update has to do in target rows

Comment: it is working finally... now i understood the merge functionality actually.. thanks for ur valuable guide man.. definetely your codes and advice can help lot of people... thanks again..

Comment: You can close this now... your code and logic is absolutely fine.

Comment: Hi Damien, I have used this merge statement. I am getting this error.Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL.
But in both update or insert, i am not trying to insert NULL value. What might be the problem.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever Hi Damien, I have used this merge statement. I am getting this error.Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL. But in both update or insert, i am not trying to insert NULL value. What might be the problem

Comment: @Robin - a) If this is based on the later examples above, make sure that `@nowdate` isn't NULL, b) Check whether there are other columns in the table that don't accept NULLs. Otherwise, not sure at the moment.

Comment: There is some column which wont accept NULL in target table. During insert im passing appropriate value to this. But during updates, im not touching these columns. Im updating only few columns.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever is it required to update all the NON NULL columns

Comment: @Robin - no, it shouldn't be. I'm trying to think through what it could be (other than, as I say, verifying that any parameters, such as `@nowdate,` genuinely aren't NULL)

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever @nowdate is not null for sure. i tried with print the value of the parameter also. There is no other parameter im using here except this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out one of those many links:

- [Using SQL Server 2008's MERGE Statement](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/Using-SQL-Server-2008-s-MERGE-statement/0,339028455,339283059,00.htm)
- [MERGE on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)
- [Introduction to MERGE statement](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/)
- [SQL Server 2008 MERGE](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/davidportas/archive/2007/11/14/SQL-Server-2008-MERGE.aspx)

Without actually knowing what your database tables look like, we cannot be of more help - you need to read those articles and figure out yourself how to apply this to your concrete situation.