# SQL Server 2008 MERGE with Target as table with no values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

I want to do  MERGE from a source to a Target where I insert rows if they don't exist and update the ones that do.  When I do this, I get only inserts... no updates.  I read this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015623/merge-query-in-sql-server-2008), which is a bit confusing for me to follow, but it seems that I need a duplicate source to make this happen.  Can someone explain why a DUPLICATE source would be required?   I just don't get it, especially which keys I should be using (duplicate source or regular ones)-- Maybe the duplicate SourceTable is just not needed?

here my (simplified) SourceTable :

```
   row   userid   placervalue   placerDt
   ---   -------  ----------    ----------
   1     abc      a1            1/1/12
   2     xyz      b1            1/1/12
   3     abc      b2            1/20/12
   etc.
```

and my target TargetTable that is same, but currently with no rows in it.

```
   row   userid   placerId   
   ---   -------  ----------
  (nothing loaded yet)
```

what I want is to INSERT rows that are NOT in the target, and UPDATE rows that are.

```
   row   userid   placervalue   placerDt
   ---   -------  ----------    ----------
   1     abc      a1            1/20/12  *** note change here (row 3 updates row 1)
   2     xyz      b1            1/1/12
```

When I run this code, I get only inserts (would also like to know why)

```
MERGE TargetTable as t
USING SourceTable as s
   ON s.userid = t.usrid AND s.placervalue = t.placervalue
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE
      SET t.placerDt = s.placerDt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (
       userid
     , placerid
     , placerDt
   ) VALUES (
       s.userid
     , s.placerid
     , s.placerDt
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont have rows on your destination table, there is nothing to MATCH, that's why you only get inserts.

Run the query a second time that you should have updates

Comment: Expanding on Diego's answer - the logic only applies to the data that is in the table prior to executing the merge, not the data that is in the table part way through.You could create a view that only returns the most recent valid row (according to whatever criteria you specify) and the use that as the source for the merge.

Comment: I read somewhere that MERGE is a set operation --- is this what this means? to ask this another way: if record1 is an INSERT, and if record2 matches record1, will SQL Server see that record1 is now in the record & I get the UPDATE of record 1?  Or do I get the update on the NEXT time I try to MERGE (because it's operating on the full set)?  The post I found seems to imply that MERGE can operate row by row.

Comment: think of merge like a copy from source to destination, BUT if the row already exist in the destination it is updated instead of copied

Comment: Thanks Steve and Diego.  I think I get it.  The implications of this are also that if I have NEW duplicate data in the source table that I want to MERGE, (all of) the NEW dups will be inserted, since they will not match any recs during the MERGE.