# SQL query for update and insert data in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i`m trying to update my table and i want to check if there was a record before it do nothing and if it was different it change it and if it was not there insert new one , here is my table fields :

```
id  res-id   req-id   IsActive
--  ------   ------   --------
```

and here is my stored procedure :

```
@Res_id int,
@Opt_id int,
@IsActive int
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
SET XACT_ABORT ON  

BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[res_opt_junc]
            WHERE [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id AND [IsActive]=1 AND          @IsActive=1)
        BEGIN
        RETURN;
        END; 

ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[res_opt_junc] 
            WHERE [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id AND [IsActive]=0 AND @IsActive=1)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[res_opt_junc]
            SET    [Res_id] = @Res_id, [Opt_id] = @Opt_id, [IsActive] = @IsActive
            WHERE  [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id AND [IsActive]=0 AND @IsActive=1           
        RETURN;
        END;
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[res_opt_junc] 
            WHERE [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id AND [IsActive]=1 AND @IsActive=0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE [dbo].[res_opt_junc]
            SET    [Res_id] = @Res_id, [Opt_id] = @Opt_id, [IsActive] = @IsActive
            WHERE  [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id AND [IsActive]=1 AND @IsActive=0
            RETURN;
        END;
ELSE IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[res_opt_junc]
            WHERE [Res_id]=@Res_id AND [Opt_id]=@Opt_id)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[res_opt_junc] ([Res_id],[Opt_id],[IsActive])
            VALUES (@Res_id , @Opt_id  , @IsActive);
            RETURN;
        END;
END
```

I don't know why my data in table got dupplicate;

Comment: What version of sql-server? You can try `MERGE`.

Comment: if you got duplicates, you miss an unique constraint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge query in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015623/merge-query-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement sounds like the tool for the job.

Example:

```
MERGE [dbo].[res_opt_junc] roj
USING (SELECT @Res_id AS Res_id, @Opt_id AS Opt_id, @IsActive AS IsActive) AS nv
ON roj.Res_id = nv.Res_id AND roj.Opt_id = nv.Opt_Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET roj.IsActive = nv.IsActive
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Res_id, Opt_id, IsActive) VALUES (nv.Res_id, nv.Opt_id, nv.IsActive)
;
```

Given, of course, that `Res_id` and `Opt_id` are components of a primary key.